Are there examples of convergent improper integral but we can not apply FTC?
I want to find examples of improper integral such that
(1) the lower and upper limits of the integral are finite
(2) the improper integral is convergent,
(3) the integrand is expressed as one equation,
(4) if we just apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, then the value is wrong.
In other words,
$\int_a^b f(x) dx = M < \infty$ for some $a, b, M\in\mathbb{R}$, but $F(b)-F(a)\neq M$ where $F(x)$ is an indefinite integral of $f$.
I guess it would be possible, but I cannot find such a case.
Please let me know such an example.

I suppose if you integrate $f=I_{\mathbb{Q}}$ on $[0,1]$ in the Lebesgue sense, you get 0, but that's not $F(1)-F(0)$ given that $F$ doesn't really exist due to it not being Riemann integrable.

To clarify, you're not asking for "examples" of the type$$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{2}} = -\frac{1}{x}\bigg|_{-1}^{1} = -2,$$right? (The integral here is not well-formed because the integrand is unbounded near $0$, but does have a "wrong" formal value.)

@AndrewD.Hwang Sorry, I've just considered Riemann integration. So, I want to consider an example similar with your second example. But, the improper integral has no value, so it does not fit to (2). For instance, $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ is also such an improper integral, and the integrand is unbounded near 0, but the value is finite when we calculate it with limits. But, the value is the same as the result obtained by applying FTC (thought the way to calculate is wrong).
